# How can I loop to get dates of next 10 days from today using carbon in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, laravel-blade

I've been trying to create a dropdown of the next 10 days (along with the day optional) in Laravel `blade.php` I was able to get the current date using `\carbon\carbon::now();` but when I try to add a day in the same variable it gives an error

**Here is my Code-**

```
<select class="form-control">
    <?php
     $today = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('m-d-Y (l)');
     $iterate = 0;
     for($iterate=0;$iterate<10;$iterate++) {
    ?>
        <option value="{{$today}}">
           {{$today}}
        </option>
    <?php
     $today = $today->addDay(); } //this one isn't working
    ?>
</select>
```

**The Error-** 
`[2021-10-22 01:21:32] local.ERROR: Call to a member function addDay() on string (View: /var/www/vhosts/example.com/dummy.example.com/resources/views/superadmin/side_menu_superadmin.blade.php)`

How can I work it out,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CarbonPeriod` to generate range of dates. Try this code

```
@php
$now = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$startDate = $now->clone()->startOfDay();
$endDate = $now->clone()->addDays(10)->endOfDay();
//change 10 to whatever you needed
$datePeriod =  collect(Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, $endDate)->toArray())
              ->map(function($eachCarbonDate){
                return $eachCarbonDate->format('m-d-Y (l)');
              });
@endphp

<select class="form-control">
  @foreach ($datePeriod as $eachFormattedDate)
      <option value="{{$eachFormattedDate}}">
           {{$eachFormattedDate}}
        </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Here is the live demo link to [phpsandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/small-wood-vr1b-zb84a?files=%2Fresources%2Fviews%2Fwelcome.blade.php)

Comment: And its better to pass the data from controller to blade. Its not wise to use php tag inside blade.

Comment: You are right. 
I understand, but in this case, I wanted to display that particular dropdown on a popup for some reason which would be displayed on each and every page. whenever a user logs in for the first time and
I didn't know any other way around it

Comment: you can use view composer https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers